# How to be notified only once for new Gmail emails?

Tags: iphone, gmail, ios, notifications

I've just moved from Android to iPhone and I'm struggling to configure my Gmail notifications to work in the same way.

On Android, I had it configured so that I didn't receive further notifications until I dismissed the previous one. If there was more than one unread email, the icon would be a multiple-envelope symbol (otherwise it was a single envelope).

In case that wasn't clear, here's a little timeline of events for my Android Gmail app:

```
Email arrives --> Notification!
Email arrives
Email arrives
<clear notifications>
Email arrives --> Notification!
Email arrives
```

Using the Gmail app on my iPhone 6, I am notified about every email that arrives. Is there any way to replicate the behaviour I enjoyed on my Android phone?

Looking in the settings on the GMail app, I notice the Notifications section only has two options: *All New Emails* or *None*. So I'm not holding out too much hope here...

Comment: I am not clear what you want. What is first email and not subsequent? Subsequent from same sender ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 The "first email" is the first email received from anyone since I  dismissed the previous notification. Have tried to clarify in question.

Comment: This seems useful to me. I'm kind of surprised there is no mail client or setting to do that filtering. I can only assume the notification isn't run from he app, but the OS in this case,..